# Angular - clear form input after submit

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple form like so:

```
<form name="add-form" data-ng-submit="addToDo()">
    <label for="todo-name">Add a new item:</label>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="toDoName" id="todo-name" name="todo-name" required>
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

with my controller as follows:

```
$scope.addToDo = function() {
    if ($scope.toDoName !== "") {
        $scope.toDos.push(createToDo($scope.toDoName));
    }
}
```

what I'd like to do is clear the text input after submission so I simply clear the model value:

```
$scope.addToDo = function() {
    if ($scope.toDoName !== "") {
        $scope.toDos.push(createToDo($scope.toDoName));
        $scope.toDoName = "";
    }
}
```

Except now, because the form input is 'required' I get a red border around the form input. This is the correct behaviour, but not what I want in this scenario... so instead I'd like to clear the input and then blur the input element. Which leads me to:

```
$scope.addToDo = function() {
    if ($scope.toDoName !== "") {
        $scope.toDos.push(createToDo($scope.toDoName));
        $scope.toDoName = "";
        $window.document.getElementById('todo-name').blur();
    }
}
```

Now, I know that modifying the DOM from the controller like this is frowned upon in the Angular documentation - but is there a more Angular way of doing this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When you give a name to your form it automatically gets added to the `$scope`.

So if you change your form name to "`addForm`" ('cause I don't think `add-from` is a valid name for angular, not sure why), you'll have a reference to `$scope.addForm`.

If you use angular 1.1.1 or above, you'll have a [`$setPristine()`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/733a97adf87bf8f7ec6be22b37c4676cf7b5fc2b) method on the `$scope.addForm`. which should recursively take care of resetting your form. or if you don't want to use the 1.1.x versions, you can [look at the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/733a97adf87bf8f7ec6be22b37c4676cf7b5fc2b) and emulate it.

Comment: Thank you! Although I still have to clear the model the $setPristine() handles the blurring nicely. 'add-form' seems to work, and I can access it with $scope['add-form'] rather than dot notation.

Comment: Yeah, the clearing of the model is always a must, because the $setPristine doesn't know about your model. Thanks for letting me know about the name! missed that completely thought I shouldn't have :)

Comment: t = {}; t.foo-bar = "baz";
ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: how do you use $setPristine?

Comment: $scope.form-name.$model-property.$setPristine() for property level or $scope.form-name.$setPristine() for form level (affect all form controls)

Answer (score 2):

For those not switching over to 1.1.1 yet, here is a directive that will blur when a $scope property changes:

```
app.directive('blur', function () {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.blur, function () {
        element[0].blur();
    });
  };
});
```

The controller must now change a property whenever a submit occurs.  But at least we're not doing DOM manipulation in a controller, and we don't have to look up the element by ID:

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.toDos = [];
    $scope.submitToggle = true;
    $scope.addToDo = function () {
        if ($scope.toDoName !== "") {
            $scope.toDos.push($scope.toDoName);
            $scope.toDoName = "";
            $scope.submitToggle = !$scope.submitToggle;
        }
    };
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="toDoName" name="todo-name" required 
  blur="submitToggle">
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BzjztTLvOfzfLHz5XKKk?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you. Thats handy to know until 1.1.1 rolls out.

Answer (score 0):

I have made it work it as below code.

**HTML SECTION**

```
<td ng-show="a">
 <input type="text" ng-model="e.FirstName" />
</td>
```

**Controller SECTION**

> e.FirstName= '';