# Resetting form after submit in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi I have a form which does update on button click.

```
 $scope.action = "Update";
  var id = $routeParams.editId;
  scope.item = updateRecord.get({ id: id });
```

Once the item is updated it doesn't remove the entered information in the form fields. I was wondering what is available in angularjs to add in the above code after udpating so that it also clears to form. 
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684877/angular-clear-form-input-after-submit/14685706#14685706

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can reset a form by, `$scope.formName.$setPristine();` but if you're binding a model object to your inputs, you need to take care of clearing those too, ie:

`$scope.currentRecord={};`

**EDIT**

As ToodoN-Mike pointed out, don't forget to set

`$scope.formName.$setUntouched()`

The `$touched` flag was introduced in angular 1.3.

Comment: Don't forget to use $scope.formName.$setUntouched() -> $touched flag was introduced in angular 1.3

Comment: clear the form by using `$scope.currentRecord={};` is wrong approach, try to reset the field by using empty works fine.

Comment: @MohammadFareed `currentRecord` was merely used as an example to refer to the current form model, it's not a real object on the `$scope`

Answer (score 46):

At the bottom of your submit function's body run this code below.

```
// Reset the form model.
vm.project = {};
// Set back to pristine.
vm.form.$setPristine();
// Since Angular 1.3, set back to untouched state.
vm.form.$setUntouched();
```

"vm.form" is my form name.

For more info have a look at this docs page:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

Comment: Can you please tell me why this approach is not working with this approach i.e. I am using this in controller instead of $scope.

Comment: Just to clarify. If your controller as an alias (strongly recommended with vm), you can set an attribute like `name='vm.form'` to the form element. An object will then be exposed to your current scope (which is vm). All you got to next is reset `pristine` and `touched` values and reset the `ng-model` of your inputs.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me.

```
viewModel.data = {};
$scope.formName.$setUntouched();
$scope.formName.$setPristine();
```

Answer (score 3):

1) To Remove the values in Form Fields and to reset you can use [$setPristine();](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setPristine)

```
$scope.formName.$setPristine();
```

2) Next, to set the form to Untouched State too use [$setUntouched();](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setUntouched)

(If you have **required fields** in your form Fields and also if you are using **ng-messages** then if you don't use the below function those fields will show error.)

```
$scope.formName.$setUntouched();
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont get the question, but maybe, you can clean the form in the Html component:

function: ngSubmit(), send the data.
taskName is the name of the field, also taskBody.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(taskName.value, taskBody.value); taskName.value=''; taskBody.value=''" #taskForm="ngForm">
```