# Resetting the model values

Tags: angularjs, forms, reset, angular-ngmodel, ng-submit

I have an `ng-model="name"` in my html page. It is connected to the main controller. The model is used to submit the name in a form using `ng-submit= formfilled(name)`. But after the form is submitted, I want the name input field to be blank again. How can I do this?

I was trying to do `$scope.name = ""` on my controller after the form is submitted, but it's not working.

If I understand correctly, the `ng-model` creates the name you give it as a variable in the scope right?

Comment: `ng-model="name"` will create property `name` in `scope`, indeed. Can you show us how do you clean name value on form submit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571370/resetting-form-after-submit-in-angularjs