# Reset form when i click modal pop up close button (x) in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have form in modal pop up.i am using directives for opening the modal pop up

```
mymodule.directive('modalDialogSite', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      show: '='
    },
    replace: true, // Replace with the template below
    transclude: true, // we want to insert custom content inside the directive
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.dialogStyle = {};
      if (attrs.width)
        scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
      if (attrs.height)
        scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
        if (attrs.overflow)
        scope.dialogStyle.overflow = attrs.overflow;
      scope.hideModal = function() {
        scope.show = false;
      };
    },
    template: "<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'><div class='ng-modal-overlay'></div><div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'><div class='ng-modal-close' ng-click='hideModal()'><i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i></div><div class='ng-modal-dialog-content' ng-transclude></div></div></div>"// See below
  };
});
```

If i click cancel button in modal popup i use $setpristine to reset the form but If have any validation error when i click close button (x) it calls hideModal() function so modal get closed but if i reopen the modal pop the validation error still exists in modal popup.How can i reset that form.Here My working Plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/embFJFmautH3uRbHOWU7?p=preview

Comment: use $scope.formName.$setPristine();
refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21571392/6804648

Comment: @ Ushma Joshi Thanks for your response but i have already done reset when clicking cancel button like you said but when i click close button (x) in modal pop i am not able to pass the form name.Is there any solution?

Comment: can you share your html code?

Comment: I have a button when i click it calls controller
<a role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="add_site()" data-backdrop="static">
<i class="icon-columns"></i><b>Add Site</b></a>

<modal-dialog-site show='modalShown_add'>
   <?php echo $this->load->view('site/modal/add_site');?>
</modal-dialog-site>

in my controller 

mymodule.controller('myCrtl',function($scope){
 $scope.modalShown_add = false;
 $scope.add_site = function(){
  $scope.modalShown_add = true;
 }
});

Comment: if you want plnkr just go to https://plnkr.co/edit/bvBMx5Da5jBogayx1K1E?p=preview but it will not work you can see only coding

Comment: Can you provide a working plunkr as https://plnkr.co/edit/bvBMx5Da5jBogayx1K1E?p=preview is not working

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/hogjXxJSPkehGshKrWuq?p=preview try this plunker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have missed several things here. I have created a plunkr for this and it very much self explanatory. You can go over to it and observe that it is exactly what you need. The form inside the modal gets to its initial state when it is opened and the code is well organized in this working plunkr. Also the form is reset when you open the modal.

```
app.directive('modalDialogAdd', function() {

    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      show: '='
    },
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.dialogStyle = {};
        scope.text ={
        first_name : '',
        last_name: ''
      };

        if (attrs.width)
            scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
        if (attrs.height)
            scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
        if (attrs.overflow)
            scope.dialogStyle.overflow = attrs.overflow;
        scope.hideModal = function() {
              scope.show = false;
        };
           scope.$watch('show', function (newVal, oldVal) {
              if(newVal){
                  var childFormController = element.find('form').eq(0).controller('form');
                  childFormController.$setPristine();
                  childFormController.$setUntouched();
              }
          });

    },
        template: "<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'><div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal()'></div><div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'><div class='ng-modal-close' ng-click='hideModal()'><i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i></div><div class='ng-modal-dialog-content' ng-transclude></div></div></div>"
    };
});
```

Here is a working plunkr [PLUNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/jzcv8BAh7CtBf55tXPlj?p=preview)

Comment: hi AKA ,Thank you for responding this issue.Here my working plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/embFJFmautH3uRbHOWU7?p=preview

Comment: Actually my logic is totally different from your code just check this plunker

Comment: just check my plunker.The scenario will be different from what you did.could you  please  try my code?

Comment: Click on first name then click on last name, close the modal, open it again. You will find the difference.

Comment: yup its working fine when i click cancel button but instead of cancel button if i click (x) symbol in modal head it is not working

Comment: in my code i gave (x) symbol in template within directive.Is there any solution to reset the form when i click (x) symbol  which is from directive template?

Comment: It is working there as well. I can see that working.

Comment: but in your plunker once i click (x) symbol close modal pop up,again i am not able to open the modal again

Comment: Please upvote the answer if it is really helpful to you.

Comment: sure @AKA No words to explain about you...You are really great man thank you so much for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147709/discussion-between-user7098427-and-aka).